# Operation count: Solving Ax=b with sparse diagonal matrix

Tags: performance

I've seen several tables that list operation counts for matrix-inversion related problems, but none of them actually brought forward the way of computing them.

I'm interested in solving

```
Ax=b
```

for `x`, and `k`-diagonal sparse matrix `A` - which is a sparse matrix that has zero elements on all but `k` many diagonals. On these `k` diagonals, it can have either zero or non-zero elements.

I'd like to find out the number of operations as a function of `N`, the length of `b`, and `k`, the number of diagonals in `A`.

Is there an explicit answer? How could I compute it?

Comment: Which operations do you want to count? The number of scalar multiplications and additions? Only one of those? Maybe more? Of what procedure do you want to count the operations? A given algorithm (which?) to solve the equation? Or do you want a lower bound on the number of operations required to solve the equation?

Comment: What's a `DIA` sparse matrix?  I am not familiar with the `DIA` acronym.  Can you define it in a self-contained way?  Is it important?

Comment: @Discretelizard Ultimately, I want a metric of how solving time increases in `k` and `N`. I thought that the number of total operations would be a good approximation to that, but perhaps that was naive. Yes, perhaps a lower bound is a good idea.